# Constructional proof of ellipse property

Tags: conic-sections, geometric-construction

I came across the fact that the following function defines a family of ellipses with focal distance $f$, parameterized by the value of the function:

$$\frac{x-f+\sqrt{(x-f)^2+y^2}}{x+f+\sqrt{(x+f)^2+y^2}}=\text{const.}$$

I was able to convert this expression algebraically into the canonical form of the ellipse (very lengthy calculation), and I found a short neat proof that uses the geometric definition of the ellipse, as such:

Define the projected distances of the point to the foci:
$$x-f=z_1,\quad x+f=z_2$$
And real distances of the point to the foci:
$$\sqrt{(x-f)^2+y^2}=r_1,\quad \sqrt{(x+f)^2+y^2}=r_2$$
By properties of ellipse, we have
$$r_2+r_1=2a,\quad z_2-z_1=2f$$

Add and subtract these two equations:
$$(r_2+z_2)+(r_1-z_1)=2(a+f)$$
$$(r_2-z_2)+(r_1+z_1)=2(a-f)$$
Multiply top by $r_1+z_1$ and bottom by $r_2+z_2$:
$$(r_2+z_2)(r_1+z_1)+\color{red}{(r_1-z_1)(r_1+z_1)}=2(a+f)(r_1+z_1)$$
$$\color{red}{(r_2-z_2)(r_2+z_2)}+(r_1+z_1)(r_2+z_2)=2(a-f)(r_2+z_2)$$
Left hand sides are identical because the red parts equal through Pythagoras' theorem to the same perpendicular distance of the point $(x,y)$ to the $x$ axis, so we retrieve
$$\frac{r_1+z_1}{r_2+z_2}=\frac{a-f}{a+f}$$
QED.

> Can you help me find a *constructional* geometric proof (no algebraic
>   manipulations, such as difference of squares and
>   addition/subtraction of equations)?

I'm having difficulty finding a construction that puts $r+z$ on the same line, and to prove a ratio of two such distances are constant (similar triangles?). I tried with circular directrix, but I can't relate $r_1+z_1$ to $r_2+z_2$.

Comment: If you divide the numerator and denominator of $(a-f)/(a+f)$ by $a$, you get $(1-e)/(1+e)$, where $e$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse. That is, you have shown that your ratio is constant for *the family of ellipses with the same eccentricity*, not *a family of ellipses [merely] with focal distance $f$*. But, ellipses with the same eccentricity are similar, so the constant-ness of the ratio across that family is unsurprising. Still, the fact that $(r_1+z_1)/(r_2+z_2)$ gives the eccentricity expression is interesting.

Comment: $a$ is not a constant of the whole family, it is set by which ellipse you pick (set by $r_1+r_2$). It's only constant along an particular ellipse.

Comment: Right. So saying that "the following function is constant on a family of ellipses with focal distance $f$" is inaccurate, as it suggests that $f$ is the only relevant value, whereas that function also depends upon $a$, which is not constant across the family.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the fact that your final equation isn't invariant under exchange of indices (i.e., exchange of foci) suggests that it should only be true over a restricted stretch of the ellipse; the fact that some of your quantities (e.g. $x-f$) can go negative suggests that geometric interpretation will be at least slightly more complicated.  It might be worth trying to figure out the region of 'geometric validity' of this statement (i.e., when all distances are assumed to be unsigned rather than signed).

Comment: Here's an alternative derivation, using the parameterization $(x,y)=(a \cos t,\sqrt{a^2-f^2}\,\sin t)$. First, note that we have $$\begin{align}(x\pm f)^2+y^2 &=a^2\cos^2t \pm 2a f\cos t+f^2+(a^2-f^2)\sin^2t \\ &=a^2\pm 2af \cos t+f^2\cos^2 t \\ &= (a\pm f\cos t)^2\end{align}$$ Since $a>f$ in an ellipse, we know that the positive square root of the above —that is, the unsigned distance, $r_i$, from a point on the ellipse to a focus— is simply $a\pm f \cos t$. So, the function is $$\frac{a\cos t - f + (a - f \cos t)}{a\cos t+ f+(a + f\cos t)}=\frac{a-f}{a+f}=\frac{1-e}{1+e}$$

Comment: There's an interesting geometric interpretation of the fact that $r_i = a\pm f \cos t$. We know that the parameterization $(a\cos t,b\sin t)$ describes cutting origin-centered circles of radius $a$ and $b$ with a line at angle $t$ to the $x$-axis, and letting the intersection points determine a point on the ellipse in the appropriate way. If we cut an origin-centered circle of radius $f$ with that same line, then the projection of *that* intersection point onto the major axis divides that axis into precisely the lengths $r_1$ and $r_2$. I don't think I ever noticed that before.

Comment: Interesting, I never considered polar coordinates! This might lead to a constructional proof I'm looking for, as now I can have both $r$ and $z$ on the $x$ axis.
I was concerned about the domain, too, but it seems to work for the entire euclidean plane, except for the negative $x$ axis where some limits are needed to extend the definition.
I also reworded the first line to convey the meaning I was referring to.